# Displaying Sharepoint User profile information and creating custom search

Tags: sharepoint

I have to display user profiles along with their properties in a gridview in a Sharepoint application. Post that it should display results based on the search criteria being made.
I have tried using foreach loop using UserProfileeManager, but it seems very slow when a search is made for 3000 user profiles.
Is there any way to store all the user profile information somewhere in SQL database, or If any webservice can be used.

Kindly help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going for seperate SQL DB.

Get the user profile details and store it in SharePoint list on your site.

Perform the search on that list so that it will increase the performance.

To display in gridview you can do it in lot of ways if the data in SharePoint List.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

don't understand your platform clearly,since you already known store the info in DB,just store it,such as MySQL of windows,*nix and SQLite for android and iOS.Good luck. u wanna do some search,then if it is simple find ,the use sql 'select xxx,yyy from table where ....';that's ok.Good Luck.

Comment: No actually it is not advisable to perform a select query on sharepoint content database where all user profiles are stored. So Is there any way of fetching the user information from sharepoint site.